# Why is $H_1(N_g)=\mathbb{Z}^{g-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, quotient-group

I've got a question from example 2.37 from Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

In that example there's the chain complex coming from the cell decomposition of a non-orientable surface of genus $g$, $N_g$:

$0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{d_2}\mathbb{Z}^g\xrightarrow{d_1}\mathbb{Z}\to 0$

where $d_1=0$ and $d_2(1)=(2,\dots, 2)$. Since $d_1=0$, $H_1(N_g)=\mathbb{Z}^g/\mathrm{Im}(d_2)$. I would say that the quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, but Hatcher says

> If we change the basis for $\mathbb{Z}^g$ by replacing
>   the last standard basis element $(0, \dots , 0, 1)$ by $(1, \dots , 1)$, we see that $H_1(N_g) ≈
> \mathbb{Z}^{g−1}⊕\mathbb{Z}_2$.

It is true that $d_2(1)=0\cdot(1, \dots , 0, 0)+\cdots +0\cdot (0, \dots , 1, 0)+2\cdot (1, \dots , 1)$, so I guess that's where we get $\mathbb{Z}^{g−1}⊕\mathbb{Z}_2$ from.

But why was my first intuition wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of $d_2$ is a copy of $\Bbb Z$ inside $\Bbb Z^g$. So the quotient
of $\Bbb Z^g$ by $d_2(\Bbb Z)$ will be an Abelian group of rank $g-1$.
For $g\ge2$ that will be a group containing a copy of $\Bbb Z^{g-1}$
so certainly infinite, and not torsion (unlike $\Bbb Z_2^g$).

Comment: That makes sense, but what is wrong with using the standard basis and saying that since $d_2(1)=2e_1+\cdots+2e_n$ then the quotient is just quotienting out each coordinate? If this is wrong, what is the reason why the change of basis works fine?

Comment: @Javi quotienting out by each coordinate would be taking the quotient by the subgroup generated by $\{2e_1, 2e_2,\ldots, 2e_n\}$. The subgroup generated by $d_2(1)$ is strictly smaller.

Comment: If you quotient out $\Bbb Z^n$ by the group generated by $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, what do you think you get? @Javi

Comment: If I think it in a more abstract way, just thinking "$(1,\dots, 1)$ generates a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ so the quotient must be $\mathbb{Z}^{g-1}$" I get it, but when I try to think it as a subgroup I get confused.